# Python - what is the best practise for returning a class variable?

Tags: python

I am currently learning OOP and I have created a class that stores a dict as a variable `self.foo`. I have created a method `bar` that returns `self.foo`:

```
class FooBar:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = {}

    def bar(self):
        return self.foo


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FooBar()
```

My question is this. Calling the class variable directly and using the `bar` method produce the same results, which is the correct method for accessing `self.foo` or doesn't it make a difference?

Here are some examples:

```
>>>test = FooBar()
>>>test.foo['test'] = 'This is a test'
>>>print(test.foo)
'{'test': 'This is a test'}'

>>>test.bar()['test_2'] = 42
>>>print(test.bar())
'{'test': 'This is a test', 'test_2': 42}'
```

Comment: "which is the correct method for accessing self.foo" — depends what the class is for and how it is documented.

Comment: You might want to read about the `@property` decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/295246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways are correct and it doesn't make much difference which one you choose. The approach with the `bar(self)` method is the classical "getter" approach that is often used in other OO languages to access typically private members but as in python every member is public by default it doesn't make a difference if you use your getter method `bar(self)` or call the member foo directly.

Alternatively, to the getter method you can also use the `@property` decorator if you want to access the member `foo` with a different name. But if you don't need to do anything with the `foo` member before accessing and returning it by another name you can also simply add a reference to the `foo` member as `self.bar = self.foo` in your constructor such that you are able to access the member under a different name. (I think it is overdoing to creating a method or use a property just to access the member under a different name I would use the reference to the member, but that is my personal preference).

However, if you want to mark that the member should be treated as private and should be modified only within the class or with a setter method it is common practice to start the member name with a `_` such as in `_foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `property` decorator.

If you're directly returning the variable from function then that's wrong, the reader might think that there will be some computation or modification in the called function, but in reality, you're just passing the variable so property decorator will give more clear context to the reader.

```
class FooBar:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = {}
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self.foo
```

Then access it like,

```
>>>test = FooBar()
>>>test.foo['test'] = 'This is a test'
>>>print(test.foo)
'{'test': 'This is a test'}'

>>>test.bar['test_2'] = 42
>>>print(test.bar)
'{'test': 'This is a test', 'test_2': 42}'
```

Comment: "You should _always_ use the `property` decorator"? What does that even mean? In every situation, a property is always the appropriate choice?

Comment: @khelwood added the explanation.